# Correct way of using Twitter Bootstrap Thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the following markup on [my website](http://www.ps-vitamins.com.php54-2.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/) towards the bottom of the page. This is using [Twitter Bootstrap Thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails).

Is this the correct way of setting it up? If it is, why are the thumbnails not stacking up correctly? (notice the gap that occurs after the first row). I'm trying to avoid wrapping every 4 products inside a row.

Thanks for any help.

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-weight-management">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/PSPrenatal.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">
                <div class="caption">
                  <a href=""><h3>PS Prenatal</h3></a>
                  <p>Superior Multivitamins for Mom & Baby</p>  
                </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-weight-management">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/PSSleepAid.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">                
              <div class="caption">
                <a href=""><h3>PS Sleep Aid</h3></a>
                <p>Restful Sleep Formula</p>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-multivitamin">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/PSPerformance.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">
              <div class="caption">
                <a href=""><h3>PS Performance</h3></a>
                <p>All Natural Male Performance Formula</p>  
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-multivitamin">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/VitaminD3_2000_big.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">
              <div class="caption">
                <a href=""><h3>PS Vitamin D3 2000 IU</h3></a>
                <p>Supplement Facts</p>  
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-weight-management">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/PSPrenatal.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">
                <div class="caption">
                  <a href=""><h3>PS Prenatal</h3></a>
                  <p>Superior Multivitamins for Mom & Baby</p>  
                </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-weight-management">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/PSSleepAid.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">                
              <div class="caption">
                <a href=""><h3>PS Sleep Aid</h3></a>
                <p>Restful Sleep Formula</p>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-multivitamin">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/PSPerformance.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">
              <div class="caption">
                <a href=""><h3>PS Performance</h3></a>
                <p>All Natural Male Performance Formula</p>  
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mix category-multivitamin">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href=""><img src="/assets/img/sample-products/VitaminD3_2000_big.jpg" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="outer-caption">
              <div class="caption">
                <a href=""><h3>PS Vitamin D3 2000 IU</h3></a>
                <p>Supplement Facts</p>  
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: If you look in Firebug the 1st image is a full 30px taller than the image in the last column. That pushes the next row out of alignment. Size images to be consistent, and set a height for them instead of "height:auto" ... Answer below beat me to it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because thumbnails use `display: inline-block`, and **your first element is higher** than the other. Set a height on these thumbnails (or use uniformized pictures) to avoid gaps :

```
.product-categories .thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    height: 430px;
}
.product-categories .thumbnail .outer-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;   
}
```

I added a few CSS to align captions.

[image]